# How to properly get an instance of WifiManager in MainActivity and Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio, wifimanager

According to the Android Documentation for [WifiManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html) you:

> Get an instance of this class by calling Context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE).

---

In both **Fragment** and **MainActivity** calling:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = Context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
```

returns the error:

> Non-static method 'getSystemService(java.lang.String)' cannot be referenced from a static context.

---

In **MainActivity** calling:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
```

works but, why does the Documentation state otherwise?

Can someone help me understand why we no longer need to prefix `Context` to `getSystemService()` even though that method belongs to the `Context` class. Also why are we casting to `(WifiManager)`? This explanation will help me tremendously as this isn't the first time what works varies from what the Documentation prescribes.

---

In **Fragment** calling the same:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
```

returns the error:

> Cannot resolve method 'getSystemService(java.lang.String)'

---

I would like to be able to get the instance in the fragment because of the problem I described in my last [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34420956/variable-populated-when-accessed-from-mainactivity-but-null-when-accessed-from-f).

---

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `getActivity()` method to call `getSystemService` method from `Fragment` like:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getActivity().
                         getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
```

Because `getSystemService` method is from Context class instead of from `Fragment`

Answer (score 0):

Warning for those looking for the solution for an `Activity` and not a `Fragment`, `WifiManager` should be retrieved using:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = mContext.getApplicationContext()
                                  .getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
```

Holding WifiManager with respect to a context other than one at the Application level will cause memory leaks.

From [Android Developer Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager):

> On releases before `Build.VERSION_CODES.N`, this object should only be
>   obtained from an `Context#getApplicationContext()`, and not from any
>   other derived context to avoid memory leaks within the calling
>   process.